Enquiry on a claim in Titchmarsh.
There is a claim on p.107 of Titchmarsh's ''The theory of the Riemann zeta function'', that if $0<a<b \leq 2a$ and $t>0$, then
the bound
$$\sum_{a <n <b} n^{-\frac{1}{2}-it} \ll (a/t)^{1/2} + (t/a)^{1/2} \tag{1}$$
follows from
$$\sum_{a <n <b} n^{-it} \ll t^{1/2} + at^{-1/2} \tag{2}$$
''by partial summation.'' Titchmarsh doesn't include any details of the proof, but from the partial (Abel) summation formula:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula
it's not clear to me how (2) follows from (1). Can someone kindly fill in the details omitted by Titchmarsh?

Is this really what the book says? How are inequalities defined for complex numbers?

@geetha290krm, $a, b$ and $t$ are all positive real numbers. And yes, that's what the book says: chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/EM18/TitchmarshZeta.pdf

The school level topic "algebra-precalculus" doesn't seem very appropriate as a tag for this question. Probably "riemann-zeta" and/or "analytic-number-theory" would be better.

Explain the meaning of $\ll$. I don't see such a  statement on p.107. There is no $<$ or $\ll$ for complex numbers.

@geetha290krm, Titchmarsh uses the Big Oh notation $O$, on the right-hand side of his inequalities. It's exactly the same as $\ll$.

@DaveL.Renfro, corrected, thanks.

Summation by parts has several variants. We use the following.
Define $a(n) = n^{-it}$ for $n \geq a$. Define its partial sum from $a$ by $A(u) = \sum_{a \leq n \leq u} a(n)$. Then Titchmarsh apparently showed that
$$ A(u) = O(t^{1/2} + a t^{-1/2}) \qquad (u > a).$$
Partial summation (in the way coming directly from Riemann-Stieltjes integration) says that for a $C^1$ function $f$, we have
$$
\sum_{a < n \leq b} a(n) f(n)
=
A(b)f(b) - A(a)f(a) - \int_a^b A(u) f'(u) du.
$$
Apply this with $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$, which is $C^1$ for $x > 0$. Then we find
$$
\sum_{a < n \leq b} n^{-\frac{1}{2} - it}
=
A(b)/b^{1/2} - A(a)/a^{1/2} + \frac{1}{2} \int_a^b A(u)/u^{3/2} du.
$$
The integral is logarithmic in size, which Titchmarsh ignores. The initial sums are bounded in the big-Oh sense by
$$ (t^{1/2} + at^{-1/2}) / b^{1/2} + n^{-it}/a^{1/2}
\ll
(t/b)^{1/2} + a/(tb)^{1/2}
\ll
(t/a)^{1/2} + (a/t)^{1/2}.$$
We've used that $b > a$ in the final simplification, though it's not obvious why such a symmetric form is desirable. I didn't look at the linked document to see what's done with it.
